# TinyMCE increase font family dropdown font sizes

Tags: tinymce

Does anyone know how I can increase the font size of the 'font family dropdown' list items in TinyMCE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create an own css file and use the tinymce configuration parameter

```
content_css : your_css_file.css,
```

Your css file will have to contain the following. You may adjust the font-size here

```
.mceMenu span.mceText,.mceMenu .mcePreview {
    font-size: 11px;
}
```