# change tinymce font family menu's font size

Tags: tinymce, themes, font-size

I've checked this: [TinyMCE increase font family dropdown font sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115747/tinymce-increase-font-family-dropdown-font-sizes) but my question is a little bit different. I want the font size to be changed **dynamically**, when a tinyMCE instance is instantiated on a specific textarea.

So I made a CSS file saying this:

```
.mceMenu span.mceText,.mceMenu .mcePreview {
    font-size: 14px !important;
}
```

And added it at runtime like this:

```
tinyMCE.settings['content_css'] = "css/tinymcearabic.css";
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, myel_id);
```

I have checked and the path is correct. But it didn't seem to make a difference.

### Edit

If I add the CSS directly onto the page that I'm using TinyMCE, then the font does get bigger, but I can't keep it that way because the menu depends on the event that triggered it.

So I then tried to edit it dynamically using this:

```
$('.mceText').css('font-size','20px');
```

Again no use.
Here's a fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/EBcaab

Any ideas?

### Edit 2

The effect that I'm looking for is easy to get on the fiddle above if this is hard coded into the code:

```
<style>
.mceMenu span.mceText,.mceMenu .mcePreview {
    font-size: 14px !important;
}

</style>
```

The only problem is that's a static solution while I need to get this effect dynamically.

Comment: can you create a tinymce fiddle for this? (fiddle.tinymce.com/)

Comment: i've edited the question and added the fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you will need to use an init object and assign a different content_css when you reinit your editor. Have a look at this fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/FBcaab/1 .
You will need to create the css file and use the content_css parameter to embed it on init.

Comment: I just tried what you said but it didn't work. Did I do it right? I added an absolute path right there on the fiddle, see here: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/GBcaab

Comment: By the way, why should `tinyMCE.settings['content_css'] = "css/tinymcearabic.css";` be wrong? Is it wrong, or is it supposed to be right while I might be messing something else up?

Comment: no, tinyMCE.settings['content_css'] = "css/tinymcearabic.css" is not wrong, but it is safer to set the value before init because some settings get applied during initialization and changing them afterwards won't do a thing